# Declaring 2d array in XNA

Tags: xna, shader, hlsl

6 images 800x640 need to be rendered from a point of view, and based on these images one new image 800x640, a sort of fish-eye view, should be created.
At the moment the application draw each image and read the colors by calling this RenderTarget2D.GetData method and based on each pixel position it calculates new position for that final image. It works fine.

but since calling RenderTarget2D.GetData reduces the performance I tried to declare a 800x640 array in shader and then render 6 images consecutively. Then in pixel shader find the new coordinate of the new fish-eye view image.

```
float4 PSTooBasic(VertexPSInput pin) : COLOR
{
    int xCoord = GetWaldXCoordinate(pin.PositionWS.x); 
    int yCoord = GetWaldYCoordinate(pin.PositionWS.y);

    WaldPixs[xCoord][yCoord] = 1; 

    return BlackColor;
}
```

But this array declaration line:
uniform int WaldPixs[800][640];

gives this compile error: error X3059: 'WaldPixs': array dimension must be between 1 and 65536

Any suggestion or workaround?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems that shader doesn't support 2d arrays or it's just too big.

Comment: The latter: "it's just too big".

Comment: I know that in HLSL, tex2D returns the value of a texture data. I was wondering if there is a way to set a value on tex2D at specific location?

Comment: Pixel shaders (in xna) do not support scattered writes, it's only possible in dx11 with a shader model 5.0 card (you can write either in pixelshader of compte shader in that case). If you give little more details (like small screenshot of the 6 pictures/final image), maybe can find some workaround for you ))