# Set data in a 2D texture in HLSL

Tags: shader, xna-4.0, hlsl

I know that in HLSL, tex2D returns the value of a texture data. I was wondering if there is a way to *set* a value on a 2D texture at specific location?

Or what is a way (if there is any) to save values for say 800x640 elements in HLSL. Initially I though the way is to declare an array of that size but the compiler gives error as it's too  big. That's why I am asking of the possibility of setting data in a 2D texture.

Comment: You can render a scene to a `RenderTarget2D` and then access that later as a texture. But this is the kind of question where you should really say what you are trying to achieve - because the thing that you've asked to do is pretty unusual.

Comment: If you need to set a value on a Texture2D you don't need HLSL, you can use Texture2D.SetData (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.setdata.aspx). Anyway saving 800x640 elements in an array is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have explained the problem here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145237/declaring-2d-array-in-xna) as well.

Comment: You can see that the performance problem due to several calls to Texture2D.GetData is a lot, so I thought instead of "each time(6 times in total to create one final image) calling this GetData method and creating new image based on its return value(color[])" I can call Draw method once and in pixel shader  fill in the renderTarget and call the GetData method once at the end.